# Why ajax won't populate my ul list?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

All need is that ul list is populated with data from php code,on page load.Thanks in advance,and sorry if I am not exact,I am new here.This post is mostly code.

**Here's the code of ajax function:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var podtip="proba";
            $.ajax({
                url: 'php/dodajTVpocetna.php',
                type: 'POST',
                cache:false,
                data: { target: podtip },
                success: function (data) {

                        $('#slider ul').append(data);
                    }

            }); 

        });
```

**Here's the code of php  file:**

```
$q = $_POST['target'];
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","iptv");
                        if (mysqli_errno($conn)) {
                            die("Neuspjela konekcija: " . mysqli_connect_error());

                    }
                else{
                    $upitM='SELECT * FROM stream WHERE Kategorija="Music" ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,1';
                    $music=mysqli_query($conn,$upitM);

                    $upitF='SELECT * FROM stream WHERE Kategorija="Movies" ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,1';
                    $film=mysqli_query($conn,$upitF);

                    $upitS='SELECT * FROM stream WHERE Kategorija="Series" ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,1';
                    $series=mysqli_query($conn,$upitS);

                    $upitN='SELECT * FROM stream WHERE Kategorija="News" ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,1';
                    $news=mysqli_query($conn,$upitN);

                    $upitMO='SELECT * FROM stream WHERE Kategorija="More" ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 0,1';
                    $more=mysqli_query($conn,$upitMO);


                    if(!$music)echo'greska je "'.mysqli_error($conn).'"';

                    while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($music)) != NULL) {
                            $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($news);
                            $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($film);
                            $row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($series);
                            $row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($more);
                            print_r(error_get_last());
                            echo"<li><div class=\"tv\"><a href='javascript:changeVideoJW(\"".$row['Link']."\");'>".$row['Naziv']."</a></div></li>
                                <li><div class=\"tv\"><a href='javascript:changeVideoJW(\"".$row1['Link']."\");'>".$row1['Naziv']."</a></div></li>
                                <li><div class=\"tv\"><a href='javascript:changeVideoJW(\"".$row2['Link']."\");'>".$row2['Naziv']."</a></div></li>
                                <li><div class=\"tv\"><a href='javascript:changeVideoJW(\"".$row3['Link']."\");'>".$row3['Naziv']."</a></div></li>
                                <li><div class=\"tv\"><a href='javascript:changeVideoJW(\"".$row4['Link']."\");'>".$row4['Naziv']."</a></div></li>";
                            }

            mysqli_close($conn);
                }
```

**HTML list:**

```
<div class="w3-third">
  <div id="liquid1" class="liquid">
    <span class="previous"></span>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul id="slider">


        </ul>
    </div>
   <span class="next"></span>
</div>
</div>
```

I used ajax before,and it worked this way.

Comment: Could You please print data ...??
What are you getting there ..

Comment: Why you've used so many queries. You can get data from single one. : `SELECT * FROM stream WHERE Kategorija in ("Music","Movies","Series","News","More") ORDER BY rand()`

Comment: I am getting just empty list..

Comment: Sometimes, all it takes is one complete debugging routine. Walk behind your code step by step and check where the problem occurs. Then post the error Or the line where you find things go wrong. This way we all can go home early :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to accumulate the final `HTML` content on each iteration through resultset rows.
 Change your `while` loop as shown below:

```
$content = "";
while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($music)) != NULL) {
                            $row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($news);
                            $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($film);
                            $row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($series);
                            $row4 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($more);
                            //print_r(error_get_last());
                            $content .= "<li><div class=\"tv\"><a href='javascript:changeVideoJW(\"".addcslashes($row['Link'],'"')."\");'>".addcslashes($row['Naziv'],'"')."</a></div></li>";
}
echo $content;
```

Add `dataType` option into your ajax request object to get response from server as `HTML`:

```
...
dataType : 'html',
...
```

Also, append response data as HTML as shown below:

```
...
$('#slider ul').html(data);
...
```

Comment: Chrome consol log say this:  Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list  index2.php:144

and on line 144 in index2.php is $('#slider').append(data);
what should i do?

Comment: I suppose that there is(are) unescaped quotes in some of those variables `$row['Link']` or(and) `$row['Naziv']`. Check my update

Comment: Aslo if i change echo $content with this echo '<li><div class="tv">AAA</div></li>'; nothing is added in slider

Comment: If I put php on same page and call php self it works,but like this does not...when I put last update it show no errors but there is no data in slider...I am sure your code is ok,but ajax wont work on my xampp,hope I will figure out where is problem

Answer (score 0):

first of all check your query , that return values and works fine use:

`print_r($film)` and other query result to see what happens at the end.

next you dont need to use

`$('#slider ul').append(data);`

use this:

`$('#slider').append(data);`

Answer (score 0):

Change your PHP code with this :

```
$q = $_POST['target'];
    $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","iptv");
                        if (mysqli_errno($conn)) {
                            die("Neuspjela konekcija: " . mysqli_connect_error());

                    }
                else{
                    $upit='SELECT * FROM stream WHERE Kategorija in ("Music","Movies","Series","News","More") ORDER BY rand()';
                    $all=mysqli_query($conn,$upit);

                    if(!$all)echo'greska je "'.mysqli_error($conn).'"';
                    //uzimamo vrijednosti svih proizvoda za zadati podtip,smjestamo ih u div elemente i prikazujemo na pocetno
                    $ht = "";
                    while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($all)) != NULL) {

                            print_r(error_get_last());
                            $ht .= "<li><div class=\"tv\"><a href='javascript:changeVideoJW(\"".$row['Link']."\");'>".$row['Naziv']."</a></div></li>";
                            }

            mysqli_close($conn);
            echo $ht;
                }
```

And your js code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var podtip="proba";
            $.ajax({
                url: 'php/dodajTVpocetna.php',
                type: 'POST',
                cache:false,
                data: { target: podtip },
                success: function (data) {

                        $('#slider').append(data);
                    }

            }); 

        });
```